Kibana "drilldown to discover" with time layers?
I have bar graphs in Kibana dashboard panels that have multiple layers from different time ranges. My "drilldowns to discover" stops working when I have these extra layers.
Is there a way to apply the drilldown to only one of the time zones? Or is there some workaround so I can have these time layers but still have "drilldown to discover"?
I've deleted these extra layers and the drilldown starts working again, so I know that is the cause.
